# ajax call not finding php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi i am trying to create a registration page using ajax and php I am trying to send my values to my php page, although, I can seem to get the file path correct. any suggestions would be mostly appreciated.

ajax url

```
url:'../../includes/validation/page.php',
```

file structure

```
main folder
     assests folder
             js folder
              ajax.js

     includes folder
              validation folder
                    reg.php
form.php
```

Comment: Does it not go through the file it was called from? So `includes/validation/page.php`?

Comment: What page are you calling this URL *from*?  Where in your file structure is `page.php`?

Answer (score 2):

The URL must be a link to the resource such as

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/includes/validation/reg.php',
    type: 'get'
});
```

The file must also be publicly accessible.